# Android recycleView with NativeExpressAd so laggy

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob

I have this little sample code for recycleView with nativeExpressAd.

Activity:

```
public class RecycleViewAd extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    // Native Express reklámok és lista elemek listája
    private List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycle_view_ad);

        context = RecycleViewAd.this;

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
//        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        // Lista feltöltése
        mRecyclerViewItems = new ArrayList<>();
        addMenuItems();


        // Specify an adapter.
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mRecyclerViewItems);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And here is the Adapter:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE = 0;

    private static final int NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE = 1;

    private final Context mContext;

    private final List<Object> mRecyclerViewItems;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Object> recyclerViewItems) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mRecyclerViewItems = recyclerViewItems;
    }


    public static class MenuItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView menuItemName;
        private TextView menuItemDescription;
        private TextView menuItemPrice;
        private TextView menuItemCategory;
        private ImageView menuItemImage;
        private CardView row;

        MenuItemViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            menuItemImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_image);
            menuItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_name);
            menuItemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_price);
            menuItemCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_category);
            menuItemDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_description);
            row = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_card_view);
        }

    }

    public static class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        NativeExpressAdView adView;

        NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            adView = (NativeExpressAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice("B9EE0FBCF9F3B7065A60A390FC73594D")
                    .build();

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mRecyclerViewItems.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return (position % mContext.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.items_per_ad) == 0) ? NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE
                : MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE;

    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                View menuItemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.menu_item_container, viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new MenuItemViewHolder(menuItemLayoutView);
                break;
            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                View nativeExpressLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(
                        viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.native_express_ad_container,
                        viewGroup, false);
                viewHolder = new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(nativeExpressLayoutView);

        }
        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

        switch (viewType) {
            case MENU_ITEM_VIEW_TYPE:
                MenuItemViewHolder menuItemHolder = (MenuItemViewHolder) holder;
                MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) mRecyclerViewItems.get(position);

                // Get the menu item image resource ID.
                String imageName = menuItem.getImageName();
                int imageResID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable",
                        mContext.getPackageName());

                // Add the menu item details to the menu item view.
                menuItemHolder.menuItemImage.setImageResource(imageResID);
                menuItemHolder.menuItemName.setText(menuItem.getName());
                menuItemHolder.menuItemPrice.setText(menuItem.getPrice());
                menuItemHolder.menuItemCategory.setText(menuItem.getCategory());
                menuItemHolder.menuItemDescription.setText(menuItem.getDescription());

                break;
            case NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_VIEW_TYPE:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Can you help me what did I do wrong because with this solution the recycle view lagging when the adView comes in the list.
Without ads it's smooth.

Thank you!